# Tutorial for Examine/Lucene

Tags: .net, search, lucene, lucene.net

I am interested in [Examine](http://examine.codeplex.com/)  for building searching in a standalone desktop app for searching db tables as well as office/.pdf files

This looks like an excellent scenario for Lucene/examine

However the doc there is minimal and while i have plenty of experience with SQL full text search, Lucene is a different beast altogether and hence looking for help/pointers on how/where to start

And yes, i did a google search but did not find any resources as the terms are fairly common ( lucene examine tutorial etc. )

Comment: Freeware is free the because developers are not paid - all work is voluntary.  Very few developers volunteer to write  documentation.  Nature of the beast.

Comment: @Blam that's understood, hoping someone somewhere wrote a little more detailed how to before i dig in

Comment: @Blam: I'll take the bait: Lucene is not Freeware but Open-Source. There is a lot of documentation available on Lucene, but the problem is, it's shattered and novices will have a hard time getting into it without a decent introduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to know is that Lucene.NET is a line-by-line port of Lucene. Only minor aspects of it are specific to .NET, so most things you'll find for Java Lucene, will hold for the .NET version too. That alone is enough material for a lively discussion about how to port a Java project to .NET. Actually, the project has just graduated as a full-blown Apache project, after years of incubating.

Now, I agree with Vedran that the [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) book is a real treat, not only to get up to speed pretty fast (and God knows, Lucene is speedy), but also to get into the gory details that help you solve problems.

If you want to start from online material, it looks like [this intro](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/07/30/LuceneIntro.html) can give you a hand. It's almost 10 years old, but from a quick glance, I'd tell it generally still stands. It addresses both aspects of searching (indexing/querying) while demonstrating it with actual Java code which should be easily portable to C#.

#### In short, these are the highlights

1. To write to an index, you use an *IndexWriter*
2. To query an index, you release a query on an *IndexSearcher*
3. The writer takes an *Analyzer* (default is StandardAnalyzer) which defines how text gets stored and/or indexed
4. To create a query, you can use a *QueryParser* (which also takes an Analyzer), or build the query object yourself.

With this info, you can already setup a minimal working example.

#### Analyzers

The next step is to dig into the tokenizing. Different analyzers do different tokenizing. They allow you to ignore short words, split up at non-alphanumeric characters or do stemming (SnowballAnalyzer). Getting to know which analyzers are available and picking the right one is essential to make Lucene a fit for your problem.

#### Querying

Indexed data can be queried in, I'd say a flexible way but with its own limitations. Due to the nature of Lucene, things like negation, sorting and ranges can give you a major headache.

The one thing you have to realize is that Lucene is actually nothing more than an ultra-efficiënt dictionary you can do lookups with. This explains for example why negations are peculiar. You cannot search for the absence of something, but you *can* search for "MyField:false". Searching for a number between 1 and 3, will generally create a query looking for 1, 2 and 3. And while handling dates, you have to make sure they are indexed in a sortable way (e.g. 20121005)

#### Community

If you run into problems: the [Lucene.NET newsgroup](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-user/) has shown to be pretty helpful and responsive.

#### SOLR.NET

Chances are you'll run into some limitations, like the need for faceting. [SOLR.NET](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) is built on top of Lucene.NET and solves some things that would otherwise require you to go at great lengths. I've never actually used it though.

#### Examine

I've also no experience with Examine, but from what I quickly see, it just relieves the burden from handrolling your queries.

Comment: Great Lucene summary and high level intro.

Comment: thanks for the intro, I have tried some small samples with lucene a couple of times and got as much but never enough to actually get it working in the real world and that's why i ended up using SQL Full-text search, came across similar issues and to SOLR .. examine and picked on examine for it's ease of use over SOLR but looks like there's no easy way out other than to dive in, setup IFilter's and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I once needed to work with CLucene, which is C++ implementation of Lucene APIs. It proved to be a very difficult task until I ran into [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) book. Although the samples were all in Java, and there are some differences in APIs, the book explained concepts in Lucene very clearly, so I just used that knowledge and used it in CLucene. The book is ~470 pages long, but you can get by with first three chapters.

I know this is not a Lucene/Examine tutorial suggestion, but it's really worth a shot, because the Examine is just a simple wrapper around Lucene. Once you get the concepts, the Examine itself should become obvious.